# Microsoft Graph API, Get SharePoint Site Admin/Members

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to use Microsoft's Graph API to iterate through Sharepoint sites, in order to find and remove a user's access to sites when they go out of the country.

Graph / Sharepoint API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0

I get a list of all sites using the Get Sites endpoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites`

I then filter out personal / OneDrive sites, and try to use the List Site Permissions endpoint to try to get admins/members: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Unfortunately, I get an empty `value` array in response for all sites:

```
{'@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('<domain>.sharepoint.com%asdfasdgsdf-ca8f-4ec1-bb3e-sdfsdfsdgsdf%2Cbed949c3-3f83-47c2-a263-sdfsdfsdgasdf')/permissions", 'value': []}
```

I know that the query is fine, because if I change it to instead hit the Site Lists endpoint, I get a response which includes various values:

```
{'@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('<domain>.sharepoint.com%sdfsdfsdgsd-7dce-4564-9de8-eb2dfc02eb86%sdfsdgsdfsdf-ab8c-464f-a77d-sdfsdfsdgsdg')/lists", 'value': [{'@odata.etag': '"sfwsdgsdg-aff1-4295-8443-sdfsdgasdf,7"', 'createdDateTime': '2020-08-26T16:17:41Z', 'description': 'This library contains items that have been modified or deleted but must remain available due to eDiscovery holds. Items cannot be modified...
...
```

So, the Site ID I am passing to the permissions request must be correct. Is this the wrong endpoint then? Or, is this functionality missing from the Graph API, and my only solution is via the SP Powershell module?

I have tried with both the `v1.0` and `beta` vesions of the API.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permissions from Graph API seem to be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66901339/permissions-from-graph-api-seem-to-be-empty)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It looks like there was never any resolution, and I do have the API permissions referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/307911/graph-api-sharepoint-site-permissions-operation-no.html) it looks like a bug in Graph API.

Comment: Sigh - that looks and sounds about right. I have had nothing but trouble working with the MS Graph API. Either random endpoints not implemented, or needing to supply `select` parameters just to get any data back. It's mildly infuriating because you never know what is wrong...

I appreciate you taking a look!